# Measuring remote desktop latency when typing

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

I'm trying to measure the lag/latency of a remote desktop connection on the client, specifically when typing, but I don't know how to do this.

For instance, I remote from my Windows 7 workstation into a Windows Server 2008 machine, open Notepad, and start typing. Is there a way to measure the delay in milliseconds between when I physically type on my keyboard and the result appears on the screen?

Note: I'm not trying to solve the latency issue. I want to measure it and prove there is a problem at all. (Running into a "it works for me" situation.)

My specific scenario is also using a Remote Desktop through Citrix, but I'm hoping there is a more general solution for Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

iperf can measure latency, jitter, and thoughput and there are server/clients for windows and linux and you can test bi-directionally.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has Performance Counters for user input delay in Remote Desktop as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-rdsh-performance-counters).

Since Windows 10 v1809 / Windows Server 2019 they should be enabled by default.

You can open Performance Monitor, click the green `+` and scroll down to choose e.g:

- `User Input Delay per Session` > `Max Input Delay` > `Max`
- `User Input Delay per Process` > `Max Input Delay` > search for `mstsc.exe` below the list

Note the units are milliseconds though Performance Monitor does not seem to indicate this.

Also the graph has a default max of 100 so go to `Action` menu > `Properties` > `Graph` tab > `Vertical scale` > `Maximum` and increase as necessary if your lines are going off the top.